# Как скорректировать код?

Tags: python, python-2.7, merge

У меня есть код, который сортирует цифры. Скажите, пожалуйста, когда нам на вход дают не только цифры, но еще и их количество, как тогда можно изменить код?

Ввод:

```
5
11 3 2 1 13
```

Вывод:

```
1 2 3 11 13
```

Сам код:

```
def mergeSort(myList):
if len(myList) > 1:
    mid = len(myList) // 2
    left = myList[:mid]
    right = myList[mid:]


    mergeSort(left)
    mergeSort(right)


    i = 0
    j = 0
    
    k = 0
    
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            myList[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            myList[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
      
        k += 1

    
    while i < len(left):
        myList[k] = left[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < len(right):
        myList[k]=right[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
a = int(input())
myList = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: Сейчас у вас что-то не получается? Если с текущим кодом что-то не так напишите об этом в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так добавьте просто `input()` :)

Для того, чтобы сделать сортировку, в Python есть функция `sorted()`, которая работает для списков. А количество нам вообще не нужно - мы его даже не записываем в переменную. Надеюсь, система примет ввод:

```
input()
print(*sorted(map(int, input().split())))
```

Наш алгоритм:

- Принимаем "количество" (которое ничего не значит)
- Принимаем числа и преобразовываем в список (функция `split()`)
- Переводим все элементы списка списка в тип `int`
- Сортируем список
- Печатаем пользователю отсортированный список

Если же система не примет такую программу, делайте так:

```
k=int(input())
sp=map(int, input().split())
sp2=[]
for i in range(k): sp2.append(sp[i])
print(*sorted(sp2))
```

А вот простой способ без `sorted()`:

```
def f(sp): return(min(sp))
input()
s=list(map(int, input().split()))
while s:
    print(f(s), end=' ')
    s.remove(f(s))
```

А если без `min`, то так:

```
def minimal(data):
    _min = data[0]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if _min > data[i]: _min = data[i]
    return _min
input()
s=list(map(int, input().split()))
while s:
    print(minimal(s), end=' ')
    s.remove(minimal(s))
```

Новый алгоритм:

- Функция `f()`:

  - Идём по элементам списка

    - Если элемент больше минимального, даём `_min` значение элемента
  - Возвращаем `_min`
- Пока введённый список не равен `[]`:

  - Печатаем минимальный элемент списка и удаляем его из списка

Помогло?

Comment: У меня условие, нужно отсортировать людей по росту. Использовать sort, sorted, index нельзя. Остается только merge сортировка

Comment: Сейчас добавлю вариант

Comment: А теперь? Нормально?

Comment: При решении нельзя пользовать методами min, index, sort, sorted. Только функциями min, max, которые принимают два числа

Answer (score 1):

В вашем вопросе нет вопроса. Не обращайте внимание на количество чисел (не цифр - иногда разница важна). Вот так можно завершить вашу программу:

```
a = int(input())
myList = list(map(int, input().split()))

mergeSort(myList)
print(*myList)
```

Но я тут по другой причине. Если вас просят написать сортировку и запрещают пользоваться стандартными средствами, отвечайте `qsort`. У неё очень простая и короткая реализация, которую не придется отлаживать. Да, это не верх эффективности, но она работает и работает быстрее чем любая другая сортировка записанная в восемь строк:

```
def qsort(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    pivot = lst[len(lst) // 2]
    less = qsort([x for x in lst if x <  pivot])
    eq   =       [x for x in lst if x == pivot]
    more = qsort([x for x in lst if x >  pivot])
    return less + eq + more


input()
print(*qsort(tuple(map(int, input().split()))))
```

Comment: Круто... Что делает `turple`?

Comment: Почти тоже что и `list`. В отличие от `list` его нельзя менять. В коде таким образом выражена уверенность что `qsort` не меняет исходный список.

Comment: спасибо) буду знать